# How to set timeout value for Spring Boot Configuration server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I have a simple setup for with with spring boot ConfigServer and a client service which is calling the ConfigServer to get the configuration prop file details from GIT.

My Config server is working properly and I am able to get the prop file form GIT. But when I am trying to run the consumer server which will get the details from ConfigServer  server I am getting one error... 
Error is as follows ...

```
Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
```

localhost:8888 is the URL for my configServer , which I able to call directly from browser , but as I have a big prop file , its taking some time to retrieve it from GIT.

Configuration at configServer (application.properties)

```
spring.application.name=config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/shibajiJava/MicroServiceDemo
spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true
```

Configuration at Consumer Service (bootstrap.properties)

```
spring.application.name=configuration-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true
```

Is there any thing to specify timeOut value at consumer end ? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

**Config server side:**

- Try setting `spring.cloud.config.server.git.timeout` to the desired value.
- Try setting `server.connection-timeout` to the desired values.

**Config client side:**

I am not aware of any property which could do the job. You might have to override the default `RestTemplate` that does the request. In order to do so, create a `RestTemplate` with the desired timeout and inject it instead of the default one (my best guess would be with the right `@Qualifier` and `@Primary` on top of that, but you should check the sources and confirm that is indeed how the default template is injected).

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("rightQualifierHere")
    public RestTemplate configRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
               .setReadTimeout(readTimeout)
               .setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout)
               .build();
    }

}
```

**Documentation:**

- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-config.adoc
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Hi @alexrolea, I am getting connection time out for "spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888" , not at the time of reading the file from github. I guess something have to do at Consumer Service bootstrap.properties. Please let me know your view ... and if you have any resolution for that...

Comment: Updated the answer, I am not aware of a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As a part of the Spring Config Client Documentation there are 2 properties available for configuring timeouts.

```
If you want to configure timeout thresholds:

Read timeouts can be configured by using the property spring.cloud.config.request-read-timeout.

Connection timeouts can be configured by using the property spring.cloud.config.request-connect-timeout.
```

[Source](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_spring_cloud_config_client)